# If I take union of the left cosets and right cosets of a subgroup, should I end up getting the original Group?

Tags: group-theory

I am really having hard time understanding the concept of cosets.
Does the cosets exhaust all elements in the subgroup?
In addition to that, can I consider cosets as subsets of the subgroup?

Comment: Yes, the left cosets form a *partition* of the group. Same for right cosets.

Comment: Yes. Cosets form a partition of the group. They are subsets of the group, they are pairwise disjoint, and their union is the whole group.

Comment: What does "add" mean here?  The *union* of all left cosets of a subgroup equals to whole *group* (the subgroup itself is just one of those left cosets, and its left cosets are pairwise disjoint).

Comment: I mean unions , sorry I will correct the term . But why do we consider only left cosets? what about right?

Comment: As an example, take $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and the subgroup of the even integers, $2\Bbb Z$, which is the coset with $0$; the only other distinct coset is the one with $1$: $1+2\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-3,-1,1,3,\dots\}$, namely the set of the odd integres. And indeed even integers and odd integers exhaust $\Bbb Z$. Of course this is only an example of a general fact that needs to be proven e.g. as in the answers hereafter.

Comment: Take a 1D subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ (i.e. a line through the origin), which is a subgroup. Its cosets are all parallel lines. These parallel lines partition the plane. (Of course here the group is abelian so there is no distinction between left/right cosets in this example.) That illustrates the concept for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fixed subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, each left coset is a subset of $G$. The set of left cosets is a partition of $G$ - every element belongs to exactly one left coset.

I think the best way to understand this concept (in fact, any new concept) is to compute some examples. Perhaps start by writing down the three the left cosets of a two element subgroup of the symmetries of a triangle.

Do the same for as many examples of subgroups you have looked at.

Comment: Why are we only considering left cosets? shouldn't we mention both left and right unless the group is abelian ?

Comment: We care about both the left and right cosets, and you should compute both.I suggested that particular calculation just to get  you started. In fact the most interesting case is when the left and right cosets are the same. Seeing examples where they are not will help you appreciate that.

Comment: I second @EthanBolker 's suggestion that you compute the three left cosets and the three right cosets of a subgroup of order two in the triangle group, and draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then you can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the *set* $G$ by
$$x \sim y \iff y^{-1}x \in H.$$
Here $x,y \in G$. So, what you learned from set theory, this yields a *partition*, and the *equivalence classes* are in this case the left cosets. Try for yourself what the equivalence should be for the right cosets. Anyhow, the union of all equivalence classes make up the whole set and are disjoint. Note that the only groups among the cosets is $H$ itself, the others do not contain the trivial element and are just sub*sets*. It looks pretty much like tiling $G$ with "copies" of the subgroup $H$ and you need $|G:H|$ (the index) such "tiles".

Answer (score 0):

i made some quick illustrations and put it into a small video.
hope it helps :)

https://streamable.com/hgw430

most of the arguments boil down to the fact that multiplying a group by a particular element is a one-to-one map.